# Okta SSO with Azure ADB2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, okta

We have a requirement to use Okta as an SSO for an application that uses Azure ADB2C as IDP. So, the basic flow will be, user signs into Okta, click on the configured application tile. In the background, Okta validates the user's identify with Azure ADB2C (this user details will be already there in ADB2C) and returns the user to the application with the token provided from ADB2C. So in short, the user will sign into Okta only and with that they should be able to enter into the application. I have been checking various blogs and discussions and nothing was pointing in this required direction. Can anyone guide me on this by providing needed documentation or necessary links?

Until now, I have tried similar to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-salesforce-saml
and https://help.okta.com/en/prod/Content/Topics/integrations/open-id-connect.htm

But the above doesn't seem to fulfill our needs. Is this possible? If not, what is the best way to implement Okta as an SSO provider with Azure ADB2C IDP?

Answer (score 2):

Follow adding a generic OIDC IDP:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-generic-openid-connect

For custom policy you need to fill in the claims provider, as an example

```xml
<ClaimsProvider>
  <Domain>Okta</Domain>
  <DisplayName>Login using Okta</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="Okta-OpenIdConnect">
      <DisplayName>OktaEmployee</DisplayName>
      <Description>Login with your Contoso account</Description>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect"/>
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="METADATA">https://okta.com.....well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
        <Item Key="client_id">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</Item>
        <Item Key="response_types">code</Item>
        <Item Key="scope">openid profile</Item>
        <Item Key="response_mode">form_post</Item>
        <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
        <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_ContosoAppSecret"/>
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="oid"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" PartnerClaimType="tid"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="given_name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" PartnerClaimType="family_name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" PartnerClaimType="iss" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="UserTitle" PartnerClaimType="UserTitle" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName"/>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName"/>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId"/>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId"/>
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin"/>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#configure-azure-ad-as-an-identity-provider-1

Reference to the OIDC tecnical profile
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect-technical-profile

To get claims from the Azure AD B2C user, read the claims first:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-user-input?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#read-and-write-a-claim

Then issue any claims into the B2C token that have been acquired during the journey
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-user-input?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#include-a-claim-in-the-token

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But here, the user needs to sign in again even after he signs in okta.com site and clicked on the tile configured in okta, right? Is there anyway to bypass that?

Comment: No they won’t, as a session at Okta already exists, therefore they are simply redirected with SSO back to AAD B2C, and AAD B2C issues a token to the app.

Comment: One more question. After the authentication from Okta, is it possible to get some claims from Azure ADB2C corresponding to that user (the same user will be there registered in the application)? The scenario is that, I need to get some customer attributes to be appended to the claims in the ADB2C generated token. These attributes will only be available for ADB2C users

Comment: Yes, you can map any claims from Okta token that B2C received, and issue them into the B2C token sent to the app. Use the output claims section to do this mapping. You might need custom policy if the user flow doesn’t provide enough mapping options. Custom policy let’s you map in any claim.

Comment: Thank you, but in my scenario, suppose I need to add a claim "UserTitle" whose value will be available only in ADB2C and Okta doesn't have such claim. How that can be added to the ADB2C token? Is that possible? So basically, other than the mapped attributes, I need to get other claims from ADB2C itself.

Comment: You need to use the custom policy example. Add an output claim in the technical profile to map the claim.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the documentation here: https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/add-an-external-idp/azure/configure-idp-in-okta/

Thank you.

Comment: I wanted to use Okta as an IDP for Azure ADB2C, not the other way. Sorry if I made confusion.

Comment: FYI: The link changed to https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/add-an-external-idp/azure/main/